# python3: overriding setter of a property

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = None
        pass

    def get_prop(self):
        print('base get prop')
        return self._prop

    def set_prop(self, prop):
        print('base set prop')
        self._prop = prop

    prop = property(get_prop, set_prop)
    pass


class Derived(Base):
    def set_prop(self, prop):
        print('Derived set prop')
        self._prop = prop
    pass


base = Base()
base.prop = 1
print(base.prop)

derive = Derived()
derive.prop = 1
print(derive.prop)
```

result:

```
base set prop
base get prop
1
base set prop
base get prop
1
```

Expecting to get `Derived set prop` since I override it in the derived class.

When I googled it, I saw annotating with `@Base.prop.setter`. I tried that as well, but that didn't work. I think it's because how they create the `Base`'s `prop` is different.

But I cannot easily update the `Base` class in this situation.

One way is to completely re-implement `prop` in the `Derive` class, but I know it's not the right way. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you assign to `Base.prop` with `property(get_prop, set_prop)`, this `property` object is instantiated with the `set_prop` function object as defined in the `Base` class. The fact that the `Derived` class inherits the `Base` class does not magically update the reference to the `Base.set_prop` method within the `property` object.

You can either define another `prop` inside the `Derived` class:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def set_prop(self, prop):
        print('Derived set prop')
        self._prop = prop

    prop = property(Base.get_prop, set_prop)
```

or you can simply use `property` as a decorator:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop = None
        pass

    @property
    def prop(self):
        print('base get prop')
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, prop):
        print('base set prop')
        self._prop = prop

class Derived(Base):
    @Base.prop.setter
    def prop(self, prop):
        print('Derived set prop')
        self._prop = prop
```

Comment: So, the only way is to re-run this `prop = property(get_prop, set_prop)` in `Derived` class?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some possible solutions.